# can I send a short voice recording to another non mobile phone

Tags: android

I would like to be able to program the Android to send a short voice recording (approx 10 word message) to a land line (i.e non mobile) phone.  Is this possible?   I have googled re this and it appears that though I can send a text message I cant do the voice message thing.  Is this still the case?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible?

Sorry, but you have no way of getting control over the in-call audio.